# Why does not ridge regression perform feature selection although it makes use of regularization?

Tags: regularization, ridge-regression

Could somebody explain why ridge regression does not perform feature selection although it makes use of regularization? So, it penalizes the regression coefficients like LASSO does, but  how come we end up with using all features for all the lambda (penalty) values in range? Why don't we end up getting some zero coefficients in case of high penalization? I know this is a very basic question, but I would appreciate any response. Thanks.

Comment: See [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/74542/why-does-the-lasso-provide-variable-selection)

Comment: Also see figure 3.11 in [ESL II](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/download.html) (page labelled "71" in the 10th printing of the book) and the nearby discussion.