# Lasso vs. Ridge Regression

Tags: lasso, ridge-regression

The **lasso** coefficients are the ones that minimize $RSS+\lambda \Sigma_{j=1}^{p} |\beta_j|$ whereas the **ridge regression** coefficients those that minimize $RSS+\lambda \Sigma_{j=1}^{p} \beta_j^2$. I don't quite see from these mathematical expressions alone why lasso will shrink some coefficients to be exactly zero, while ridge regression will shrink all the coefficients towards zero, but will not set any of them equal to zero. Can someone explain or provide some intuition for this please. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried looking this up in a textbook? It is not unusual to explain this in a machine learning textbook that covers lasso and ridge. [ISL](https://www.statlearning.com/) or [ESL](https://hastie.su.domains/ElemStatLearn/) might have a discussion of this.

Comment: @RichardHardy: I did read the explanation in ISL; it just wasn't that satisfying.

Comment: @Firebug: thank you for the link; it is exactly my question; I will digest it now.

Comment: Check https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/587492/35989