# How come ""mathematically"" that lasso shrinks the coefficient towards zero whereas ridge does not?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, data-mining, large-data

I understand them geometrically !
[image]

Comment: In what sense is geometry not mathematics?

Comment: See also: [Why does the Lasso provide Variable Selection?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/74542/7290)