# Can lasso and ridge regressions theoretically have exact same solution?

Tags: lasso, ridge-regression

Intuitively lasso leads more sparsity, but is that theoretically possible they have exact same solution vector?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they reduce to unregularized linear regression if the regularization coefficients are both 0. Or if all the points $(x_i, y_i)$ in the data have the same $y$ value,  then of course both will find $\hat \beta = \vec 0$ as the optimal solution.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, but is there a probabilistic approach like lasso leads sparsity more than ridge with x probabilty. What i mean is by isosurfaces it is obvious that lasso hits corners more likely, but by using isosurface volumes for lp norms can we make a probabilistic analysis?

Comment: @displayname -  Ridge regression never results in sparsity, if by sparsity you mean "some coefficient estimates = 0".  It shrinks all the parameter estimates towards 0, but none of them all the way.

Comment: @jbowman Is it never or results with very low probability? Is there a mathematical way to show that ridge never results in sparsity?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/74542/why-does-the-lasso-provide-variable-selection/74569#74569.