# Implementing Lasso Regression in Numpy

Tags: multiple-regression, python, lasso, numpy

I'm doing a little self study project, and am trying to implement OLS, Ridge, and Lasso regression from scratch using just Numpy, and am having problems getting this to work with Lasso regression.

To check my results I'm comparing my results with those returned by Scikit-Learn.

The coefficients for OLS can be derived from the following expression:

[image]

In numpy, this can be implemented in the following way:

```
np.linalg.inv(X.T @ X) @ (X.T @ y)
```

If I use the [boston housing dataset](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_boston.html) from scikit learn with this equation my coefficients match what's returned from scikit learn exactly.

The coefficients from Ridge Regression can be represented with the following expression:

[image]

In numpy this can be represented in the following way:

```
np.linalg.inv(X.T @ X + alpha * np.identity(X.shape[1]) @ (X.T @ y)
```

Again, if I plug in the appropriate variables for `X`, `y` and `alpha`, my coefficients match what's output by Scikit Learn's `Ridge` class.

However, I run into large discrepancies when I try to match the results from its `Lasso`.

I believe the coefficients for Lasso Regression can be derived in the following way:

[image]

I haven't seen this coded anywhere on the web, but I assume its implementation would look like this:

```
np.linalg.inv(X.T @ X) @ (X.T @ y - alpha*np.ones(X.shape[1]))
```

This returns results, but they do not match what's in scikit learn, and it's not particularly close.  If I run a Lasso regression with alpha set to 10 in scikit learn on the boston dataset half of the coefficients are shrunk to zero.  Whereas with my implementation they are shrunk only slightly.

What mistake am I making in getting Lasso to work?

Thank you.

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_(statistics)#Correlated_covariates

Comment: @DemetriPananos - ie, I'm not getting the same results because Lasso itself requires a level of independence between my variables that I don't have, so the two methods are returning different values?

Comment: Though I am not confident in the implementation of Lasso in sklearn, it could be the case that sklearn's optimizer is converging to a different a different, yet equivalent optima.  I'm about to go grab Hastie's book and see if he writes anything about this.

Comment: If you look through the documentation, the class for Lasso regression is inherited from the Elastic Net, so I believe they are implementing it as a special case of that, so maybe if I tried to do it that way I'd get better results.

Comment: Looks like the source code says they use coordinate descent.  It is likely coordinate descent converges to a different optima.

Comment: Where does the formula you quote for the lasso solution come from?  I don't believe there is a closed form solution for the lasso coefficients.

Comment: @MatthewDrury I inferred it from the answer given here:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/74542/why-does-the-lasso-provide-variable-selection

Comment: Ahhh.  That makes sense now.  Unfortunately, the formulas in that answer do not generalize to the multi feature case.  I'll write up an answer this evening that explains in more detail.

Comment: Lasso does not have closed form solution. Therefore, it is very normal to encounter such discrepancy.

Answer (score 2):

As @verdery and @Matthew Drury wrote in the comment above, there is no analytical expression for Lasso Regression like there is for Ordinary Least Square and Ridge Regression. Anyway, I tested your Ridge Regression $\hat{\beta}$ code

```
np.linalg.inv(X.T @ X + alpha * np.identity(X.shape[1]) @ (X.T @ y)
```

I used an X-matrix of shape (1600,12). What happened is that $\hat{\beta}$ (which is supposed to be a (12,1) shaped array/vector) became a (12,12) shaped matrix.
Then I did a change in the code and wrote it like this instead:

```
np.linalg.inv(X.T.dot(X) + alpha * np.identity(X.shape[1])).dot(X.T).dot(y)
```

Now I got the right (12,1) shape of my $\hat{\beta}$ vector