# How does Ridge regression / Regularization help in selecting less or more important features?

Tags: regression, feature-selection, multicollinearity, regularization, ridge-regression

Can someone please explain how regularization helps to shrink the " less important " features to zero ? As far as I know , Regularization only penalizes the weights of ALL the features to get them closer to 0 , so that they don't overfit to the training data . But how does it help in feature selection or deal with multicollinearity ?

Can someone please explain this in detail in a more intuitive manner ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/74542/276972

Comment: If you haven't take your time to go through these [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ctmNq7FgbvI), helped me a lot and they are described in detail and very intuitive.