# Variable selection for multiple regression from large number of predictors

Tags: multiple-regression, feature-selection, r-squared

I have 20 response variables $Y = (Y_1, \dots, Y_{20})$, and 1600 predictor variables $X = (X_1, \dots, Y_{1600})$. There are 128 observations. I wanted to know which pairs of $X$ can best predict each of $Y$.

So I generated all the combinations of $(Y_i, X_j, X_k)$ and did linear regressions for each combination to find R-squared. Based on R-squared, I extracted top 100 combinations to further analyses which pairs of $X$ are the best predictors for $Y$.

I haven't consider multicollinearity between any pair of predictors. Should I consider multicollinearity?

My goal is to find the best pairs of $X_j,$ $X_k$ that can predict a $Y_k$. Can you give some suggestions to further improve this procedure to make it statistically valid ?

Comment: How many observations do you have?

Comment: 128 observations.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is known as the $p>n$ problem, so you have more covariates than observations. In standard regression the inverse of the variance-covariance matrix is not positive definite and hence there is no solution to the normal equations (least squares estimation). One approach is to use some form of penalized regression, like [Lasso](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17251/what-is-the-lasso-in-regression-analysis) or [Ridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization) Regression. Their goal is to minimize the number of included predictors to your model.

The approach of pairwise elements of $X$ as predictors will probably always be inferior to models including more predictors, except in the special case that you know a priori that there are exactly two predictors that have to be found.

Comment: Yes, That is true, there can be more than two variables that can influence the model. But what does it means to have a high R-squred for a combination ? can we consider that combination is associated together in some way ?