# conditional quantile and conditional expectation

Tags: mean, expected-value, quantiles, conditional

I was reading some papers and I found some parts are tricky to understand.

Assume I have  price data , what does it mean to calculate the conditional mean of the price data given yesterday price ? does that mean the price is known? I know to calculate the expectation of the price I sum all the prices then divide them by the number of observation, is this is the same ?

I also came up by the terminology of conditional quantile of the price data , where the simplest way to estimate it rely on the Maximum Likelihood Estimation (MLE). I found it interesting but I could not understand how to estimate the conditional quantile by Maximum Likelihood Estimation. can anyone help me with some explanations and examples to understand. I read several papers but I could not understand.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Start with reviewing concepts such as [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability) and [conditional expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation). You can think of conditioning as of subsetting. The conditional mean for age given that the person is a female would mean just calculating the average age of all the females. In the case of "conditional mean of the price data given yesterday's price," [we are talking about](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/195044/forecasting-if-the-next-number-is-higher-or-lower/195060#195060) conditional distribution, i.e. a function that maps any possible value of yesterday's price to the expected value of the next day's price. In SQL pseudocode this basically means

```sql
WITH price_data AS (
  SELECT
    p.price AS prev_day_price,
    n.price AS next_day_price
  FROM prices AS p
  LEFT JOIN prices AS n
  ON p.date = (n.date - 1 DAY)
)

SELECT 
  prev_day_price,
  AVG(next_day_price) AS conditional_mean
FROM price_data
GROUP BY prev_day_price
```

The same would apply to conditional quantiles or other statistics. In practice though, it may be hard to calculate directly from the data because you would need to observe enough `next_day_price` data for each of the levels of `prev_day_price`, it also would be problematic if you are conditioning on a continuous variable that has an infinite number of possible levels. To solve this, we usually use statistical models: [linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) to calculate the [conditional mean](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/173660/definition-and-delimitation-of-regression-model/211229#211229) and [quantile regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_regression) to calculate conditional quantiles.

If those contents are still unclear, I'd recommend that you consult with an introductory probability and statistics handbook or a course because it might be hard to understand without understanding many related concepts.